# Order of iteration differs in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

In IE9, the numeric keys of object properties are sorted and that results in different order of iteration in IE9 compared to IE8 where the order is preserved as it is inserted.

```
var obj = {
  "5": "John",
  "1": "Kumar",
  "3": "Rajesh",
  "2": "Yogesh"
}

for(var key in obj) alert(key)
```

Result

//1,2,3,4 in IE9

//5,1,3,2 in IE8, IE7

Is there anyway I can disable this auto sorting by IE9. If not then is it possible to somehow make the browser understand that the keys should be identified as strings rather than number (but without appending any space, _ or any other special characters)

Please suggest!!

Here is the sample code snippet where I am facing this problem.

```
    function Person(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

var persons = new Object();

var p1 = Person("5","John")
persons[5]=p1
var p2 = Person("1","Kumar")
persons[1]=p2  
var p3 = Person("3","Rajesh")
persons[3]=p3
var p4 = Person("4","Yogesh")
persons[4]=p4


for(var id in personId){
   var p = persons[id];
   var option = new Option(p.name, p.id);
   select.options[select.options.length] = option;
}
```

The select options generated by this script was sorted as per the ID in IE9 where I need the same order in which it is inserted.

Comment: As I understand it object property iteration order isn't _guaranteed_ by the JS specification, so even though some (most?) browsers seem to keep the order you can't rely on it. If order is important use an array - or copy the keys into an array, sort as required, and iterate over the array to get the keys.

Comment: `var personsArray = [p1, p2, p3, p4]; for (var i = 0; i < personsArray.length; ++i) { var p = persons[i]; /* etc */ }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Property enumeration order is undefined in ECMAScript up to and including version 5 (the current version at time of writing) and does vary between browsers, so you shouldn't rely on any specific ordering. If you need predictable ordering, use an array and a `for` or `while` loop. For your example, one option would be:

```
var arr = [
  {rank: "5", name: "John"},
  {rank: "1", name: "Kumar"},
  {rank: "3", name: "Rajesh"},
  {rank: "2", name: "Yogesh"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) alert(arr[i].rank);
```

One final note: enumeration order when using a `for...in` loop is not guaranteed for any kind of object, including arrays, so you should always use `for` or `while` when order matters.

Comment: To add on, you could have an array that lists the keys in the order they should appear.

Comment: @Kolink: Agreed. I've added an example.

Comment: Probably worth being clear here that even on an array, `for..in` is not guaranteed to occur in any particular order (at least, I've never found anything in the spec that says so, and IE8 and earlier don't do them in order); [test case](http://jsbin.com/uwavoz). Some implementations put the array indexes in order even if they don't with an equivalent object (Firefox, for instance, outputs 5, 1, 3, 2 then 1, 2, 3, 5 in my linked test case), but not all. Doesn't even have to be a sparse array; [test case](http://jsbin.com/uwavoz/2). If you need order, use a `for` loop or one of the new ES5 funcs.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, the spec is explicit about the sparse array case too, in that it is covered by the regular object case. The only real difference between an array and an object in JS is the magic `length` property (plus all the extra methods of the prototype). I added a note to my answer about `for...in`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Just one more question. I am using the above mentioned obj to generate a drop down list in javascript (i.e. var option = new Option(obj.value, obj.key). The drop down list should be sorted as per the value (John,Kumar,Rajesh,Yogesh). Even though I have sorted it based on value, In IE9, its sorting based on the key(1,2,3,4) and completely makes my list jumbled. If I use arrays to store this list, will it disable this sorting?

Comment: @KumarV: If I understand you correctly, you'd have to pass a custom comparer function to your `sort()` call. Something like `arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); });`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: [Section 12.6.4](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.6.4) contains everything the spec says on the subject: *"The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified"*. Since `Array` inherits from `Object.prototype` and nothing else is stated about `for...in` behaviour, it has to follow that arrays behave the same as objects.

Comment: @TimDown: Sorry, I read your earlier statement as meaning that there was something in the spec *specific* to arrays, rather than just that general statement for objects (which of course apples to arrays as well).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That's reasonable given that I did say that the spec was specific about it, which was perhaps a little too strong :)

Comment: Thanks All. I have changed my code to use arrays instead of Object and now the ordering is same across all browsers (including IE9).