# Navigating to previous and next item in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to navigate up and down an JavaScript Object given an item of an object. An example object:

```
var items = {
   "5" : ["name", "link2"],
   "8" : ["name 2", "link 2"],
   "11" : ["name 3", "link 3"]
}
```

Now, given I have the item `items["8"]`. I want to get previous and next item respectively.

```
getItemBefore = function(index) {
    // index holds 8
    // should return "5"
}

getItemAfter = function(index) {
    // index hold 8
    // should return 11
}
```

How can I get those items?

Answer (score 14):

The keys that an object holds can be retrieved as an array with `Object.keys(<var>)`. The order of the keys in the array is arbitrary; you need to sort them before indexing. An option is the built-in `sort()` method for arrays, which is especially useful because custom comparison functions can be provided (see below). Default order is alphabetical.

Once you get the ordered array, you only need to look up where your item is in the array and return the next and previous elements from it:

```
var keys = Object.keys(items).sort();
var loc = keys.indexOf(item);
```

Given that `loc > -1` (that is, the item exists):

- Previous item: `items[keys[loc-1]]`, but check that `loc > 0` (it's not the first one).
- Next item: `items[keys[loc+1]]`, but check that `loc < keys.length` (it's not the last one).

`Object.keys` is compatible with Javascript 1.85+; [here](http://tokenposts.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/javascript-objectkeys-browser.html) is a workaround for older browsers.

### Alternative orderings

#### Numerical

If you want the keys to have a numerical order, use this comparison function:

```
var keys = Object.keys(items).sort( function(a,b) {
    return b - a;
});
```

#### Creation (or Modification) Time

If you want to work with creation order instead of alphanumeric, the items must hold their creation time. Something like:

```
<value>.index = Date.getTime();
items['<item>'] = <value>;
```

Then, the `sort()` method needs the following comparison function:

```
var keys = Object.keys(items).sort( function(a,b) {
    return b.index - a.index;
});
```

This can be easily extended to last modification ordering or similar.

#### Creation Order

Notice that the former solution only works if the items are created more than 1 ms apart, which would be suitable for user actions. If the items are added faster, use this instead of the timestamp:

```
<value>.index = Object.keys(items).length;
```

Or, alternatively, keep an external counter with the number of items in the object.

Comment: That's right, yet I think the OP does *not* want them to be sorted alphanumeric.

Comment: The only useful orderings I can think of are alphanumeric / numeric, which is already covered, and creation order... I'm adding a creation order workaround, just in case.

Comment: I'm afraid the original order is the one, which can't be reliablely kept. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) says next about the order of the returned array: "`...in the same order as that provided by a for-in loop.`" This order is not guaranteed to be the same as the creation order.

Comment: No, I meant numeric order, which was (and is) not covered. "Creation order" is somehow unreliable, and your timestamp method won't work since you can create thousands of items during the 1ms timestamp resolution.

Comment: For numeric order, just supply a numerical comparison function to `sort()`. I'm adding it. The timestamp method should work if the object holds manually generated keys, which is the use case I had in mind; then it's very unlikely that the gap is less than 1 ms. An alternative is to use the number of elements.

Comment: if `items` is an object, you can not use `.length`. you can use on keys, like `keys.length`

Comment: You mean at the beginning? That's a typo, it should indeed read `keys`. Thanks!

Comment: @lemonzi - I think you made a mistake: after your first sort-option, instead of "Previous item: `items[loc-1]`", it should say `items[keys[loc-1]]`, right (same for next obviously)? Also, `sort()` won't work properly unless you use zero's for 5 and 8: `"05", "08", "11"`.

Comment: @myfunkyside Indeed, I'm surprised nobody pointed that out! As for `sort()`, the default ordering is alphabetial, so it indeed will give a kinda awkward solution without padding. If you want numeric ordering I feel it's safer to use my alternative (define a custom comparison function that implicitly parses the string and converts it to a number) rather than zero-pad the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This answer builds upon [@lemonzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729279/lemonzi)'s answer, see [**his answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15185372/3407923) for more detailed explanations.

I just wanted to add a working example for everyone struggling with this:

```js
var items = {
  "5": ["name", "link2"],
  "8": ["name 2", "link 2"],
  "11": ["name 3", "link 3"]
};

var getItem = function(key, i) {
  var keys = Object.keys(items).sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
  var index = keys.indexOf(key);
  if ((i==-1 && index>0) || (i==1 && index<keys.length-1)) {index = index+i;}
  return items[keys[index]];
}

console.log(getItem("8",-1));
console.log(getItem("8",+1));
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p09yL01f/3/**

- This way you only need one function to change item.
- The `.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;})` [sorts the array numerical](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).
- The `if ((i==-1 && index>0) || (i==1 && index<keys.length-1)) {` checks that the item is not the first or the last index in the array, and if it is, it returns the index itself.

---

If you want to display a message if the item is the first or the last, use this instead:

```
if ((i==-1 && index>0) || (i==1 && index<keys.length-1)) {return items[keys[index+i]];}
else {return (i==1?"last":"first")+" item";}
```

```js
var items = {
  "5": ["name", "link2"],
  "8": ["name 2", "link 2"],
  "11": ["name 3", "link 3"]
};

var getItem = function(key, i) {
  var keys = Object.keys(items).sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
  var index = keys.indexOf(key);
  if ((i==-1 && index>0) || (i==1 && index<keys.length-1)) {return items[keys[index+i]];}
  else {return (i==1?"last":"first")+" item";}
}

console.log(getItem("5",-1));
console.log(getItem("11",+1));
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p09yL01f/4/**

- The `(i==1?"last":"first")` is called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), read about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky, because technically according to the ECMAScript specifications, the order of properties in an object is implementation specific.  That means there's no guarantee in the language that your properties will be in the same order each time you access them.  If you're relying on that, there's a potential there could be a problem.

See this [bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=883).  It states that Chrome doesn't promise to return your keys in any particular order, and it's been marked "WONTFIX" for 4-5 years now.  That means that you can't rely on that behavior in Chrome, and here's [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942132/order-of-iteration-differs-in-ie9) indicating that now IE9 has the same "issue".

So, I would recommend that you create your own object to manage your keys, and use a JavaScript object behind the scenes to store your keys.

Here's something I threw together, it doesn't support deletes and it has no bounds checking, but it should serve your purposes. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g7Lu6/2/).

```
function orderedObject()
{
     this.keys = [];
     this.keyIndex = {};
     this.store = {};
}


orderedObject.prototype.addItem = function(key,value)
{
     this.keyIndex[key] = this.keys.length;
     this.keys.push(key);
     this.store[key] = value;
}

orderedObject.prototype.getItem = function(key)
{
     return this.store[key];
}

orderedObject.prototype.getKeyBefore = function(key)
{
     return this.keys[this.keyIndex[key] - 1];
}

orderedObject.prototype.getKeyAfter = function(key)
{
     return this.keys[this.keyIndex[key] + 1];
}

var testObject = new orderedObject();

testObject.addItem("5" , ["name", "link2"]);
testObject.addItem("8" , ["name 2", "link 2"]);
testObject.addItem("11" , ["name 3", "link 3"]);

console.log(testObject.getKeyBefore("8"))
console.log(testObject.getKeyAfter("8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Would an array of objects be more appropriate here? The example below could be wrapped in an object and making the nextItem() and prevItem() methods. With this you might also need some bounds checking.

```
var items = [];
items[0] = {index : '5', name : 'name', link : 'link2'};
items[1] = {index : '8', name : 'name 2', link : 'link 2'};
items[2] = {index : '11', name : 'name 3', link : 'link 3'};

//then access them like this
var nextItem = function (index) {
    var i = 0,
    max = items.length;

    for (i; i < max; i += 1) {
        if (items[i].index === index) {
            return items[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return 'not found';
};

var prevItem = function (index) {
    var i = 0,
    max = items.length;

    for(i; i < max; i += 1) {
        if (items[i].index === index) {
            return items[i - 1];
        }
    }
    return 'not found';
};

//the nextItem object after 5 is shown in the console. 
console.dir(nextItem('5'));
```

Comment: I think that this method is not optimized, because at every search you are going to scan the entire array. The cost is O(n) while it could be O(1).